# NASM - How can I dynamically load a library and call its function

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64

How I can load a library from a special directory and call its function.

In normal I use `extern` for example

```
extern _fopen 

global main
section .text

main:

    xor r10,r10  

    push r10   
    mov r13, 0x6277
    push r13
    mov     rsi,rsp

    push r10   
    mov r13, 0x726964656b616d
    push r13
    mov     rdi,rsp

    call    _fopen
    mov     r14, rax
    ....
```

And load the library with `ld` in `nasm`

```
ld -o test -e main test2.o -lSystem
```

But I want to call the function without using extern.

I want to load the library dynamically by its path same `dlopen` does in **C**.

Is there another way to call a function inside a library in nasm?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `dlopen` and `dlsym` like you would in C. Of course you'd have to declare those as extern too. But you wouldn't have to link any library since they are provided by the dynamic linker dyld.

Comment: thanks Sven , please help me in this post :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119533/how-can-convert-assembly-with-extern-function-to-shellcode-in-osx-64-intel

Comment: @Sven how to do the same in windows?